# Balancing Rise and fall times at input and output in CMOS Design

Tags: cmos, rise-time

How do I make sure that my rise and fall times are balanced between input and output in a CMOS design?

Comment: Simulation of your design in whatever process node you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Scale your pull-up PMOS circuitry to have the same conductance as the pull-down NMOS circuitry. For an inverter, this means scaling the PMOS to be 2-3× wider than the NMOS, because holes are 2-3× less mobile than electrons.